# Удалить из массива первый нулевой элемент

Tags: c++

Есть, задание по работе с массивом, которое заключается в следующем:
Задан массив целых чисел X(n). Найти количество чётных элементов в массиве;
среднее геометрическое положительных элементов массива, расположенных в его
первой половине.
Все отрицательные элементы заданного массива заменить значением его
максимального элемента. Удалить из массива первый нулевой элемент.

Возникла проблема с удалением первого нулевого элемента массива.Удаление нужно выполнить с последующим сдвигом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *X,i,N,a,max;
    float sg,b,c;
    c=1;
    cout << "N = "; cin >> N;
    X=new int[N];
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cout<<"X[" << i << "]= ";
        cin >>X[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if(X[i]%2==0)
        {
            a++;
        }
        if(X[i]>max)
        {
            max=X[i];
        }
    }  
    for(i=0; i<(N/2); i++) 
    {        
        if(X[i]>0)
        b++;
        c*=X[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) 
    {        
        if(X[i]<0)
        X[i]=max;
    }
    sg = exp((1/b)*log(c));
    cout << "Колличество четных элементов массива: " << a << endl;
    cout << "Cреднее геометрическое положительных элементов массива: " << sg;
    for(i=0;i<N; i++)
    {
        cout<<"X[" << i << "]= " << X[i];
    }
    delete [] X;
}
```

Comment: логика простейшая  i = 0;  for(; i < N - 1, arr[i]; ++i) ;  while(i < N - 1)  { arr[i] = arr[i + 1]; ++i;}

Answer (score 0):

держи фулл)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout<<"Введите количество элементов: ";
    int n;
    cin>>n; // задан размер массива
    cout<<endl;
    int X[n];
    cout<<"Введите элементы массива: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>>X[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;

    // Найти количество чётных элементов в массиве
    int count_even = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (X[i] % 2 == 0) {
            count_even++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Количество чётных элементов в массиве: " << count_even << endl;

    // Среднее геометрическое положительных элементов массива, расположенных в его первой половине
    int count_positive = 0;
    double product_positive = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        if (X[i] > 0) {
            count_positive++;
            product_positive *= X[i];
        }
    }
    double geom_mean = pow(product_positive, 1.0/count_positive);
    cout << "Среднее геометрическое положительных элементов первой половины массива: " << geom_mean << endl;

    // Заменить все отрицательные элементы заданного массива значением его максимального элемента
    int max = X[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (X[i] > max) {
            max = X[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (X[i] < 0) {
            X[i] = max;
        }
    }
    cout << "Массив после замены отрицательных элементов: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << X[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Удалить из массива первый нулевой элемент
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (X[i] == 0) {
            for (int j = i; j < n-1; j++) {
                X[j] = X[j+1];
            }
            n--; // уменьшить размер массива на 1
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Массив после удаления первого нулевого элемента: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << X[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```